# ajax show hide scrolls to the top issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, css

I have used ajax show hide to display tabs. When I scroll down to the tab and click any tab it scrolls to the top of the page.

Please refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8dDat/1/

I have tried `return false`. But nothing works. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/8dDat/2/)

the problem is **height** when you click the tab the content below hide and the height become 0

So you can give css for `min-height` to the main container ie **register_frm**

See The last line of CSS

Comment: Excellent. It's working fine. Thanks so much. I have spent quite a lot of time to fix this. But you made it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    // $(id).fadeIn("slow");
    $(id).css({opacity:0}).show().animate({opacity:1}, 'slow');
```